# Embedding Ruby on Rails Project into HTML File

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

**Problem:**
I completed the Ruby on Rails "Hello World" tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) which walks you through how to build a blog. Now, I want to see if I can embed the work that I've done into an html file.

**What I've looked into:**
However, I am not exactly sure how to go about that. I looked into embedded ruby and found a good tutorial/explanation on [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/eruby.htm) and some other sites on Google. Those examples show how to write ruby code within the file though. That seems great if I'm only writing a few lines, but I want to incorporate an entire project.

I also found a link on writing [templates](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/), but that didn't seem like what I was looking for either.

**Question:**
Is there a way I can add my blog to a static html/css site that I've already created?
Something like `<% link railsblog %>`? Or is there any other way to incorporate the project on an html page?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `render` may be you looking for http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading a bit about it now. It looks like I'd have to use the embedded ruby tags and then do 'render file: filename', but I need to try it out.

Comment: `render file '/file_path/'` in erb you need to o it `<%= render file: "/path/of/the/file"> `

Comment: That wasn't it. In my html, I added <%= render file: "/path/of/the/file"> with the file being index.html.erb and it just shows up as a string of text on the web page.

Comment: @JustBlossom This entire project that you're trying to incorporate, is it a static html website ? Or a dynamic one (using databases/scripting languages)?

Comment: @ShifaKhan It's static. It is a plain site I made with CSS (and bootstrap) and HTML. My rails blog is the only thing I have that uses a database, but that's not on the site yet.

Comment: @ShifaKhan Maybe I should rephrase my question? When I run the ruby server, the tutorial spits out the display to a webpage. Instead of it displaying there, how can I display it on a site I've already made? Now that I think about it, I guess it doesn't really matter where the backend files are, I just need to make sure the index.html.erb output shows where I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a Static Html-Css website. You want to add a blog to it. Right?

The thing is, a Ruby on Rails project (eg: your blog) is not something 'additional' that you can add to a website.
It is a very powerful framework that allows you to build an ENTIRE website *within* the project.

Once you have a Rails project (your blog) running, you can put all your other existing static html, css, js files into the Rails PUBLIC folder.

Now if start up your server ( run *rails server* ), and try to access your other pages, you should see them. eg: ( localhost:3000/my-page-name.html )

Now to get localhost:3000 to point to your actual homepage.

In your 'routes.rb' file, add route:

```
root 'main#index'
```

Create a new Controller file in controllers:

```
 class MainController < ApplicationController
   def index
     redirect_to '/index.html'
   end
 end
```

You'll have to learn a couple of things about Rails if you're planning to move your entire website to Rails or if you're curious.
[This](https://medium.com/@sergiojota/how-to-learn-ruby-on-rails-with-less-pain-and-more-gain-f5b3cc66659a#.thgzx6egs) should help you get started.
Or if you're not looking to learn an entire framework for a blog, try [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-free-solution-to-add-a-blog-to-my-existing-website).

Good luck!

Comment: You can also do this `root to: redirect("/index.html")`

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was trying to do! I am definitely going to look into it some more. I was trivializing rails quite a bit, and I understand that's where I was going wrong. I was able to add everything like you said, then I created a link from my index file (now in the public folder) to my rails article that lists my blog posts, and it worked like a charm. Once again, thanks a bunch for a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to create a partial html.erb file, for intance:

```
_fileName.html.erb
```

then you can put inside your html code and render by calling:

```
<%= render 'layouts/fileName' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always render a file (e.g static form public folder) or render a view if it has a respective controller/action. Remember that to render a view you need right routing in routes.rb except rendering partials file which should start with underscore e.g _partial.html.erb

If you want to call some resource embeded in other web site you can always use  but it has nothing in common with rails.